# How to find record count for some specific tables based upon a condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a typical requirement.

I have a users table "tblUsers" in which I have two columns "UserID" and "UserEmail". The UserEmail column is not a unique column, hence two records with same email id can exists, whereas the UserID column is an identity column.

I have two more table also "tblOrders" and "tblTravelers", both of them have "UserID" column as the foreign key(linked to "tblUsers" UserID column).

Now, what I want is a stored procedure which returns me this data table :

[image]

I mean if I give "UserEmail" as parameter to the stored procedure it should return me the above table showing me the records associated with each of the UserID's, for the given "UserEmail".

Please help me out, I am a newbie to SQL Server, I know how to find out the individual records counts but I am unable to find out the solution to the above requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the data transposed - orders and travellers as columns, users as rows.

```
select users.id, users.email, 
       COUNT(distinct orders.oid) as orders, 
       COUNT(distinct travellers.tid) as travellers 
from users
    left join orders on users.id = orders.userid
    left join travellers on users.id = travellers.userid
where users.email = @email
group by users.id, users.email
```

Comment: Very nice! You may want to replace `users.email` with `@email` in the select list, letting you drop `users.email` from the `group by` clause.